# Display flex and any other HTML tag

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

Suppose this very simple case:

```css
.header-top .custom-html {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top header-has-center-sm">
  <div class="header-row container-fluid">
    <div class="header-col header-left hidden-for-sm">
      <div class="custom-html"><i class="porto-icon-shipping me-2" style="font-size: 2em; vertical-align: middle;"></i>Shipping to all states, <span style="font-weight: bold;">FREE</span> shipping to orders above $50</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col visible-for-sm header-center">
      <div class="custom-html">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col header-right hidden-for-sm">
      <div class="custom-html"><i class="Simple-Line-Icons-badge me-2" style="font-size: 2em; vertical-align: middle;"></i>All our products are <b>GENUINE</b></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the content of the `<b>` tag gets next to the surrounding words, as if there is no whitespace around it.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how to remedy it? It's the first time I notice this happening...

Basically, I set the content's display to flex, as I need to vertically align to the middle the text. But this side-effect was totally unexpected...

Comment: You have three blocks within the flex container: `<i>`, a text node, and `<b>`. Children of flex are treated as blocks. By default, flex doesn't have a gap. White-space at the beginning and end of a block is collapsed to nothing as a general HTML effect.

Comment: So is there any way to overcome this?

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to do. Maybe add a wrapper to group the inner blocks together so that the flex container only has one child.

Comment: I'm trying to do the obvious: Render the whitespaces inside the flex! Actually, I was just able to do it using the property `white-space: break-spaces;`... I'm not sure if that's the intended use of the property, but in my case, it makes things work as expected! I'll look it up!

Comment: You're applying `vertical-align: middle` to flex items. That does nothing. Has no effect. Doesn't look like you even need flex for this. Perhaps be more specific in your question.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin actually `vertical-align: middle` to the **icon** was there by the theme before I needed to align vertically the text as well... Now that I've used the flex property `align-items: center`, indeed `vertical-align: middle` is redundant, and I'll remove it altogether! Thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your text grouping. I know it sounds strange but text wrapped in div is not really grouped. You would need to wrap it in a `<span>` or `<p>` tag. I have used a `<span>` just to let the browser know that this text belongs together. You can use a `<p>` tag which obviously comes with more preset styles like margins on the top and bottom.

```css
.header-top .custom-html {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-top header-has-center-sm">
  <div class="header-row container-fluid">
    <div class="header-col header-left hidden-for-sm">
      <div class="custom-html"><span><i class="porto-icon-shipping me-2" style="font-size: 2em; vertical-align: middle;"></i>Shipping to all states, <span style="font-weight: bold;">FREE</span> shipping to orders above $50</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col visible-for-sm header-center">
      <div class="custom-html">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="header-col header-right hidden-for-sm">
      <div class="custom-html"><span><i class="Simple-Line-Icons-badge me-2" style="font-size: 2em; vertical-align: middle;"></i>All our products are <b>GENUINE</b></span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```